# How to set select options on client side with database values from server

Tags: php, jquery, json, dropdown

How can I pass a javascript variable to compare and set with PHP? I have tried the following code:

```js
      $.each(jsonData, function( index, value ) {
             var functId=value.functId;

             html +="<tr>  <td><select  id='FunctionName' ><?php foreach($conn- 
            >query( 'select resid as id ,resdesc as value  from FUNCTNAMES')- 
            >fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row){ 
     
    //how can i pass functId to compare and set in following option code ???

             $sel = ($row->id== functId)? "selected='selected'":"";
    
            echo '<option value='.$row->id.' '.$sel.'>' . $row->value . 
            '</option>';}
           ?> </select></td> </tr>";
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing client and server code on the client side. The browser (client) cannot evaluate the `<?php ... ?>` section. Instead, you should use [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) to get the database values from the server. Having said that, you have to be careful not to run these ajax calls one-by-one in a loop here. Better to execute only one ajax call to get all values at once.